# Specific template for the first element

Tags: xslt, optimization

I have a template:

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

I call it:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="paragraph"/>
```

For the first element I need to do:

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph[1]">
    ...
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/><!-- I understand that this does not work -->
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

How to call `<xsl:apply-templates select="paragraph"/>` (for the first element `paragraph`) from the template `<xsl:template match="paragraph[1]">`?

So far that I have something like a loop.

---

I solve this problem so (but I do not like it):

```
<xsl:for-each select="paragraph">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
            ...
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            ...
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this could be to make use of a named template, and have both the first and other paragraphs calling this named template.

```
<xsl:template match="Paragraph[1]">
   <!-- First Paragraph -->
   <xsl:call-template name="Paragraph"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Paragraph">
   <xsl:call-template name="Paragraph"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Paragraph">
   <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Another way, is to call apply-templates separately for the first paragraph and other paragraphs

```
  <!-- First Paragraph -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Paragraph[1]"/>

  <!-- Other Paragraphs -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Paragraph[position() != 1]"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Name your generic `paragraph` template, then invoke it by name from the `paragraph[1]` template:

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph" name="paragraph-common"> 
    ... 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="paragraph[1]">
    ...
    <xsl:call-template name="paragraph-common"/>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

A template can have both a `match` and a `name` attribute. If you set both, you can invoke the template both by `xsl:apply-templates` and by `xsl:call-template`.